# webpack files - Migration from jhipster@6.3.0 to jhipster@7.9.3

Tags: webpack, jhipster

I don't find anymore this webpack configuration in new jhipster project generated with latest version. Shall I delete or keep these part of codes ?

```
module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(j|t)s$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                'angular2-template-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'cache-loader',
                    options: {
                      cacheDirectory: path.resolve('target/cache-loader')
                    }
                },
               
                {
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        transpileOnly: true,
                        happyPackMode: true
                    }
                }
            ],
            exclude: /(node_modules)/
        }]
    }
```

Comment: JHipster 7 stopped using custom webpack configuration; now it delegates build to angular cli. So, unless you modified your webpack config, you could delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Gaël Marziou:

> JHipster 7 stopped using custom webpack configuration; now it
> delegates build to angular cli. So, unless you modified your webpack
> config, you could delete it.